# How does Thread elect a Leader device?

Tags: thread

Thread have produced a document about their protocol, [*Thread Stack Fundamentals*](http://threadgroup.org/Portals/0/documents/whitepapers/Thread%20Stack%20Fundamentals_v2_public.pdf), which I've been reading to try and understand more about how Thread works.

On page 5, the document explains that despite having no single point of failure, a *Leader* is needed to make decisions for the network:

> A Router or Border Router can assume a Leader role for certain functions in the Thread Network.
>   This Leader is required to make decisions within the network. For example, the Leader assigns
>   Router addresses and allows new Router requests. The Leader role is elected and if the Leader
>   fails, another Router or Border Router assumes the Leader role. It is this autonomous operation
>   that ensures there is no single point of failure.

How is the Leader elected by the devices in the Thread network? Is there a set of criteria that are evaluated when the devices 'vote' for or select the Leader?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great question!  I found an article from [radio-electronics.com](http://www.radio-electronics.com/articles/wireless-technology/thread-wireless-networking-for-the-iot-160) which really helps explain in some more detail how Thread works.  Basically, the first eligible router node self-designates as the leader.

In other words, when a node is added, if it is unable to find a leader in the system, it will automatically designate itself as the leader.  Otherwise, it will fall into line under the existing leader node.  I quote from the article referenced above:

> Router Eligible nodes become routers if they are needed to support the mesh. The first Router Eligible node to form the network will be autonomously designated a router as well as the Leader. A Leader performs additional network management tasks and makes decisions on behalf of the network. Other Router Eligible nodes in the network can assume the role of a Leader, but there is only one Leader per network at a given time.

In other words, it's a one <s>man</s> machine election.  Not very democratic, but in computers, it works.